# TwoLineAvatarIconListItem resize

Tags: widget, kivy, size

I have problem with size of widget TwoLineAvatarIconListItem. When there is a lot of text then i don't see all of it but only a part and dot's like these "...".

Is there any way to see all text?
I tried many things and to do a custom widget like these but I am newbie to Kivy and it's probably too hard for me.

Here is part of code.

```
def new_message(self, name, message, image_name):
    new_message = TwoLineAvatarIconListItem(text=name, secondary_text=message)
    new_message.add_widget(ImageLeftWidget(source=image_name))
    self.root.ids.list.add_widget(new_message)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Labels have a `shorten` boolean attribute. The Label widgets inside of the TwoLineAvatarIconListItem have their `shorten` attributes defaulting to `True`.

For a one-off fix, you could reference the label and set `shorten=True` for it in python.. For example:

```
    new_message = TwoLineAvatarIconListItem(text=name, secondary_text=message)
    new_message.ids._lbl_primary.shorten = False
    new_message.ids._lbl_secondary.shorten = False
    new_message.add_widget(ImageLeftWidget(source=image_name))
    self.root.ids.list.add_widget(new_message)
```

(I believe that should work, but I didn't test it, so if it doesn't let me know and I'll edit my answer)

For a permanent change, you could edit the source code of the `BaseListItem` class in the `kivymd/uix/list.py` file, and change where you find `shorten: True` in there to `shorten: False`

Comment: Yes thank you it's working ! However now there is a problem with size of widget. I'm trying to resize it dynamically with help of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788848/how-to-dynamically-resize-label-in-kivy-without-size-attribute can you tell me is this the right way to do this ?